# How to combine two $d$-degenerate subgraphs into a $d$-degenerate graph?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

A graph is $d$-degenerate if every its subgraph has a vertex of degree at most $d$. Suppose that $G$ is a graph and $G_1,G_2$ are two subgraphs of $G$ that are $d$-degenerate. Is there any way to efficiently decide whether the subgraph induced by $V(G_1)\cup V(G_2)$ is still $d$-degenerate? Furthermore, if $|V(G_1)\cap V(G_2)|$ is bounded by a constant, then is there any sufficient / necessary condition mainly relative to the structures of $G_1$ and $G_2$ so that $V(G_1)\cup V(G_2)$ induces a $d$-degenerate graph?

In order to make my quesion more precise, I expain it by an example when $d=1$.

Let $S=V(G_1)\cap V(G_2)$. If $|S|=1$, then it is trivial that $V(G_1)\cup V(G_2)$ induces a $1$-degenerate graph (forest)? If $|S|\geq 2$, we just need to test the following for each pair of non-adjacent vertices $u,v\in S$, and then can decide whether $V(G_1)\cup V(G_2)$ induces a forest.

($\star$) whether $u,v$ are in a same tree-componment of $G_1$, and meanwhile
in a same tree-componment of $G_2$?

- if the answer is YES for some pair of $u$ and $v$, then there is a $(u,v)$-path in $G_1$, and another $(u,v)$-path in $G_2$, impying the existence of a cycle in $G$, and thus $V(G_1)\cup V(G_2)$ does not induce a forest;
- if the answer is NO for every pair of $u$ and $v$, then $V(G_1)\cup V(G_2)$ induces a forest.

Therefore, while deciding whether $V(G_1)\cup V(G_2)$ induces a forest, we do not much care about vertices in $V(G_1)\setminus S$ and $V(G_2)\setminus S$, and just need to test the "local structure" of vertices in $S$.

So my previous question, in other words, is whether we can do something similar for $d\geq 2$, i.e, how to decide whether $V(G_1)\cup V(G_2)$ induces a $d$-degenerate graph just based on the "local structure" of vertices in $V(G_1)\cap V(G_2)$.

Comment: Can you precise what you mean by "efficiently decide"? Deciding if a graph is $d$-degenerate is easy, no? It suffices to remove any vertex of degree at most d and then check inductively if the remaining graph is d-degenerate (and if at any point the graph under consideration has minimum degree $>d$ then the answer is negative).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I edited my question and described what I mean by "efficiently decide". Actually, I want to decide whether $V(G_1)\cup V(G_2)$ induces a $d$-degenerate graph only based on the "local structure" of vertices in $V(G_1)\cap V(G_2)$, without testing the existence of a $d$-degenerate ordering of $V(G_1)\cup V(G_2)$.

Comment: It's easy to write down examples where the union is or is not $d$-degenerate that have no edges between vertices in the intersection.  Does that answer the question?

Comment: Many thanks but I don't quite undertand your answer. Actually, I want to have an algorithm to decide whether the union is or is not $d$-degenerate that just uses the information of the intersection. So I think examples are not enough for me...